# smarty iterate through a config file

Tags: php, smarty

Is it possible to use a while / for loop to iterate through a config file and get the key / value when you don't know the exact name but only that the item starts with "count" using a **smarty** for / while ?

e.g consider part of the config file below?

```
countUnitedStates="United States"
countUruguay="Uruguay"
countUzbekistan="Uzbekistan"
countVanuatu="Vanuatu"
countVaticanCity="Vatican City"
countVenezuela="Venezuela"
countVietnam="Vietnam"
countYemen="Yemen"
countZambia="Zambia"
countZimbabwe="Zimbabwe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the loaded config variables are accessible trough

```
{$smarty.config}
```

in the template files and

```
$smarty->getConfigVars();
```

in php

you can iterate on those and search for the string you need in the key names